# How to call functions in a strict order?

Tags: python

I've written the following functions, which should call in strict order for the correct program flow:

1. reading file config.json
2. connecting to SQL Server
3. finding all SQL files in a directory
4. execution of all SQL files and saving the results to the CSV file
5. sending CSV-file with the results in the mail
6. writing CSV-file as Google Sheet document
7. closing a SQL Server session

```py
def read_config():
    ....
    return config

def connect_to_sql_server(config):
    ....
    return connection

def find_sql_files_without_traverse(config):
   ...
   return files_list

def exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(files_list, connection, config):
   ...
   return csv_file

def send_email(csv_file, config):
   ...
   return 

def save_to_gspread(csv_file):
   ...
   return

def close_sql_server_conn(connection):
   ....
   return
```

I call the functions like this:

```py
send_email(exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(find_sql_files_without_traverse(read_config()), connect_to_sql_server(read_config()), read_config()), read_config())
save_to_gspread(exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(find_sql_files_without_traverse(read_config()), connect_to_sql_server(read_config()), read_config()))
close_sql_server_conn(connect_to_sql_server(read_config()))
```

It seems to me that this is the wrong way to call a function.

I'd really grateful for your responses.

Comment: Why not use some variables?

Comment: `config = read_config() ` once. And then use the config object in the subsequent method calls. Same goes for the other methods that return something. Just try to replicate whatever you noted down in the bullet points in the question.

Comment: Call each function separately, one by one, and assign their results (where applicable) to a variable, that you use in one of the next functions.

Comment: To me your `send_email` function should not take any input. It should call all other functions it needs, taking care of order you want.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing that is simply to call your functions in the desired order and assign the result to variables to be used as input for the next functions:

```py
config = read_config():

connection = connect_to_sql_server(config)

files_list = find_sql_files_without_traverse(config)

csv_file= exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(files_list, connection, config)

send_email(csv_file, config)

save_to_gspread(csv_file)

close_sql_server_conn(connection)
```

**Note:** I would recommend to check the different Programming Paradigms in Python and chose the one that bests fits your needs for future developments.
[Intrresting article on that subject](https://tech.peoplefund.co.kr/2018/11/28/programming-paradigm-and-python-eng.html)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do read_config() in your code, this function is called again. Your code may work, but it will run more than once.

This is bad for

**1.Speed**: Your code will be slower because you call so many functions where not needed.

**2.Readabilty**: You code will be shorter in line number but it will be harder to understand. Short codes are not good all the time.

e.g We could write c for config in short but it would not be easily understandable. Much better to write like this.

This is completely understandable and written by [Séraphin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10052161/s%C3%A9raphin) I am not going to change it, as it is completely correct.

```py
config = read_config()

connection = connect_to_sql_server(config)

files_list = find_sql_files_without_traverse(config)

csv_file= exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(files_list, connection, config)

send_email(csv_file, config)

save_to_gspread(csv_file)

close_sql_server_conn(connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd do:

```py
from contextlib import closing

config = read_config()
with closing(connect_to_sql_server(config)) as conn:
   sql_files = find_sql_files_without_traverse(config)
   csv_file = exec_sql_and_save_to_csv(sql_files, conn, config)
   send_email(csv_file, config)
   save_to_gspread(csv_file)
```